# Invalid Client Error with Client Credentials Grant

Tags: flask, authlib

I implemented the OAuth2 client credentials grant in my flask app.

Models

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))


from authlib.flask.oauth2.sqla import OAuth2ClientMixin

class Client(db.Model, OAuth2ClientMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE')
    )
    user = db.relationship('User')
    app_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('app.application_id'))
    app = db.relationship('App')


from authlib.flask.oauth2.sqla import OAuth2TokenMixin

class Token(db.Model, OAuth2TokenMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE')
    )
    user = db.relationship('User')
```

**init**.py

```
from authlib.flask.oauth2 import AuthorizationServer
server = AuthorizationServer()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...

    from app.api.auth.views import query_client, ClientCredentialsGrant
    server.init_app(app, query_client=query_client)
    server.register_grant_endpoint(ClientCredentialsGrant)
```

app/api/auth/views.py

```
def query_client(client_id):
    return Client.query.filter_by(client_id=client_id).first()


from authlib.specs.rfc6749.grants import (
    ClientCredentialsGrant as _ClientCredentialsGrant
)

class ClientCredentialsGrant(_ClientCredentialsGrant):
    def create_access_token(self, token, client):
        current_app.logger.info("RadhaKrishna")
        item = Token(
            client_id=client.client_id,
            user_id=client.user_id,
            **token
        )
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()

@auth.route('/oauth/token', methods=['POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def issue_token():
    return server.create_token_response()
```

However, I cannot get the authentication to work. I make a request to the token endpoint with the correct client credentials, scope and grant_type but get invalid_client error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://play.authlib.org? How is your client working?

Please read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=client_credentials
```

You need to send your client credentials with `Authorization` header.

Comment: Yes I did but it keeps giving Internal Server Error when trying to create a new app.

Comment: I am registering the client on the frontend of my app and generate a client ID and client secret and then I am making requests using Postman or curl. I don't use the authorize endpoint.

Comment: @radhakrishna you need to send your client credentials with `Authorization` header.